# Regex to match words with hyphens and/or apostrophes

Tags: javascript, regex

I was looking for a regex to match words with hyphens and/or apostrophes. So far, I have:

```
(\w+([-'])(\w+)?[']?(\w+))
```

and that works most of the time, though if there's a apostrophe and then a hyphen, like "qu'est-ce", it doesn't match. I could append more optionals, though perhaps there's another more efficient way?

Some examples of what I'm trying to match: Mary's, High-school, 'tis, Chambers', Qu'est-ce.

Comment: Looking at it again, (\w+([-'])(\w+)?[-']?(\w+)) will work for what I need most of the time though am still curious if there's another way.

Comment: Please give more examples and counter-examples. Which of the following are supposed to match: `"-a"`, `"'a"`, `"a'-b"`, `"a-"`?

Comment: @torazaburo There's no need for math but pretty much any word that could occur in any European language. I can add characters as necessary.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

use this pattern

```
(?=\S*['-])([a-zA-Z'-]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/267)

```
(?=                 # Look-Ahead
  \S                # <not a whitespace character>
  *                 # (zero or more)(greedy)
  ['-]              # Character in ['-] Character Class
)                   # End of Look-Ahead
(                   # Capturing Group (1)
  [a-zA-Z'-]        # Character in [a-zA-Z'-] Character Class
  +                 # (one or more)(greedy)
)                   # End of Capturing Group (1)
```

Comment: I didn't know of lookhead and it seems good. An explanation would have been nice. :) But I can read up about it. Perhaps the only guaranteed pattern that will always match.

Comment: @empedocle, an explanation added

Comment: Thanks. I also found the explanation of lookahead in Introducing Regular Expressions helpful.

Comment: Nice one :) I also hadn't understood look-ahead, but this explains it pretty good.

Answer (score 26):

`[\w'-]+` would match pretty much any occurrence of words with (or without) hyphens and apostrophes, but also in cases where those characters are adjacent.
`(?:\w|['-]\w)+` should match cases where the characters can't be adjacent.

If you need to be sure that the word contains hyphens and/or apostrophes and that those characters aren't adjacent maybe try `\w*(?:['-](?!['-])\w*)+`. But that would also match ' and - alone.

Comment: like a boss (Y)

Answer (score 11):

[debuggex.com is a great resource for visualizing these sorts of things](https://www.debuggex.com/r/E7N3Sscav7q9eFw1)

`\b\w*[-']\w*\b` should do the trick

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're running into is that you actually have three possible sub-patterns: one or more chars, an apostrophe followed by one or more chars, and a hyphen followed by one or more chars.

This presumes you don't wish to accept words that begin or end with apostrophes or hyphens or have hyphens next to apostrophes (or vice versa).

I believe the best way to represent this in a RegExp would be:

```
/\b[a-z]+(?:['-]?[a-z]+)*\b/
```

which is described as:

```
\b                   # word-break
[a-z]+               # one or more
(?:                  # start non-matching group
  ['-]?              # zero or one
  [a-z]+             # one or more
)*                   # end of non-matching group, zero or more
\b                   # word-break
```

which will match any word that begins and ends with an alpha and can contain zero or more groups of either a apos or a hyphen followed by one or more alpha.

Comment: My edited question, I think changed before you answered, did include examples like 'tis and Chambers'. Lookahead, from another answer, seems like it will catch all cases, since I'm trying to match any word that could occur in English, including cases I haven't thought of yet.

Answer (score 0):

How about: `\'?\w+([-']\w+)*\'?`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW5wN0/1)

I suppose these words shouldn't be matched:

- `something-` or `-something`: start or end with `-`
- `some--thing` or `some'-thing`: `-` not followed by a character
- `some''`: two hyphens

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
([a-zA-Z]+'?-?[a-zA-Z]+(-?[a-zA-Z])?)|[a-zA-Z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
([\w]+[']*[\w]*)|([']*[\w]+)
```

It will properly parse
"You've and we i've it' '98"
(supports `'` in any place in the word but single `'` is ignored).
If needed `\w` could be replaced with `[a-zA-Z]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another riff on similar answers:

`/\b\w+([-']\w+)*\b/g`

```
\b         # word boundary
\w+        # at least one word char
(          # followed by a group that:
    [-']   # starts with a hyphen or apostrophe
    \w+    # followed by at least one word char
)*         # and this group can appear any number of times (including zero)
\b         # word boundary
```

In my case, I needed to exclude words that start with apostrophes or hyphens, and also words with those characters repeated.

But terms like Stratford-upon-Avon are ok.

Note: I did not need to account for words starting or ending with apostrophe.