# Python regex - group

Tags: python, regex

I scraped some text from pdfs and accents/umlaut on characters get scraped after their letter, e.g.: `"Jos´e" and "Mu¨ller". Because there are just a few of these characters, I would like to fix them to e.g. "José" and "Müller".

I am trying to adapt the pattern here [Regex to match words with hyphens and/or apostrophes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910955/regex-to-match-words-with-hyphens-and-or-apostrophes).

```
pattern="(?=\S*[´])([a-zA-Z´]+)"
ms = re.finditer(pattern, "Jos´e Vald´ez") 
for m in ms:
  m.group() #returns "Jos´e" and "Vald´ez"
  m.start() #returns 0 and 6, but I want 3 and 10
```

In the example above, what pattern can I use to get the position of the `'´'` character? Then I can check the subsequent letter and replace the text accordingly.

My texts are scraped from from scientific papers and could contain those characters elsewhere, for example in code. That is the reason why I am using regex instead of `.replace` or text normalization with e.g. `unicodedata`, because I want to make sure I am replacing "words" (more precisely the authors' first and last names).

EDIT: I can relax these conditions and simply replace those characters everywhere because, if they appear in non-words such as "F=m⋅x¨", I will discard non-words anyway. Therefore, I can use a simple `replace` approach

Comment: Why don't you replace like `s.replace('´e', 'é').replace('u¨', 'ü')`? These are always parts of words.

Comment: I want to be sure that I am replacing words

Comment: But these are words. What do you mean by that? What is the context you want your match to occur in? Please clarify.

Comment: yes but I could have text where characters such as ´ appear in non-words such as code

Comment: Please check https://ideone.com/RWLqRx -  what is missing?

Comment: I guess you are right, I think I was making it too hard for myself. if those characters appear in (badly) scraped text which is not a word/name, I will get rid of those words anyway. you are welcome to publish an answer @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```py
import re
d = {'´e': 'é', 'u¨' : 'ü'}
pattern = "|".join([x for x in d])
print( re.sub(pattern, lambda m: d[m.group()], "Jos´e Vald´ez") )
# => José Valdéz
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RWLqRx).

If you need to make sure there are word boundaries, you may consider using

```
pattern = r"\b´e|u¨\b"
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/i0jx4S). `\b` before `´` and after `u` will make sure there are other word chars before/after them.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix on the pattern returns the indexes which you are looking for. Instead of matching the whole word, the group will catch the apostrophe characters only.

```
import re

pattern = "(?=\S*[´])[a-zA-Z]+([´]+)[a-zA-Z]+"
ms = re.finditer(pattern, "Jos´e Vald´ez")
for m in ms:
    print(m.group())   # returns "Jos´e" and "Vald´ez"
    print(m.start(1))  # returns 3 and 10
```

Comment: Ah, OP has already come to the conclusion that there is no need to match words. I will remove the comment.

Comment: Note the `(?=\S*[´])` is redundant here as `[a-zA-Z]+([´]+)` follows this lookahead immediately. So, the lookahead will always return *True*.