# tokenize apostrophe and dash python

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I'm tokenizing sentences with the following function using regular expressions.

```
def tokenize2(text):
    if text is None: return ''
    if len(text) == 0: return text
  #  1. Delete urls
    text = re.sub(
        r"((https?|ftps?|file)?:\/\/)?(?:[\w\d!#$&'()*\+,:;=?@[\]\-_.~]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+" +
        "\.([\w\d]{2,6})(\/(?:[\w\d!#$&'()*\+,:;=?@[\]\-_.~]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+)*",
        '', text)
    # 2. Delete #hashtags and @usernames
    text = re.sub(r'[@#]\w+', '', text)
    # 3. Replace apostrophe to space
    text = re.sub(r"'", "'", text)
    # 4. Delete ip, non informative digits
    text = re.sub(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b', '', text)
    # 5. RT
    text = re.sub(r'RT\s*:', '', text)
    # 6. Tokenize
    tokens = re.findall(r'''(?:\w\.)+\w\.?|\w{3,}-?\w*-*\w*''', text)
    tokens = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
    return tokens
```

The problem is that it removes words less than length three before the apostrophe and dash. For example for French words

```
text = "L’apostrophe, l’île, l’histoire, s’il, qu’elle, t’aime, s’appelle, n’oublie pas, jusqu’à, d’une. Apporte-m’en un. Allez–y! Regarde–le!"
tokenize2(text)
['apostrophe',
 'île',
 'histoire',
 'elle',
 'aime',
 'appelle',
 'oublie',
 'pas',
 'jusqu',
 'une',
 'apporte-m',
 'allez',
 'regarde']
```

If the word length is greater than three, then the function works fine. For example

```
text = "to cold-shoulder"
tokenize2(text)
['cold-shoulder']
```

That is, I need to remove words less than length 3, but if they are in the combination of an apostrophe and a dash, then they do not need to be removed

Comment: What I get is that you would like words with less than three characters to be removed, except when they are part of a word with an apostrophe or a dash. Am I correct in my understanding? Also, this may not be possible if you do step 3 of your function, replacing apostrophes by spaces (which will prevent recognizing a three or less characters long word from being part of an "apostrophe-ed" word)

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex do it (if I've correctly understood your goal): `[-–’\w]{3,}`

Full code:

```py
def tokenize2(text):
    if text is None:
        return ''
    if len(text) == 0:
        return text
    #  1. Delete urls
    text = re.sub(
        r"((https?|ftps?|file)?:\/\/)?(?:[\w\d!#$&'()*\+,:;=?@[\]\-_.~]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+" +
        "\.([\w\d]{2,6})(\/(?:[\w\d!#$&'()*\+,:;=?@[\]\-_.~]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+)*",
        '', text)
    # 2. Delete #hashtags and @usernames
    text = re.sub(r'[@#]\w+', '', text)
    # 3. Replace apostrophe to space
    text = re.sub(r"'", "'", text)
    # 4. Delete ip, non informative digits
    text = re.sub(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b', '', text)
    # 5. RT
    text = re.sub(r'RT\s*:', '', text)
    # 6. Tokenize
    tokens = re.findall(r'''[-–’\w]{3,}''', text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = "L’apostrophe, l’île, l’histoire, s’il, qu’elle, t’aime, s’appelle, n’oublie pas, jusqu’à, d’une. Apporte-m’en un. Allez–y! Regarde–le!"
    print(tokenize2(text))

# >> ['l’apostrophe', 'l’île', 'l’histoire', 's’il', 'qu’elle', 't’aime', 's’appelle', 'n’oublie', 'pas', 'jusqu’à', 'd’une', 'apporte-m’en', 'allez–y', 'regarde–le']
```

As I said in my comment, the Step 3 in your code was useless as the replacement character is the same as the replaced character, but had the replacement character been a whitespace as you mentioned you wanted to do in the comment, it would have been impossible for you to then parse the apostrophe correctly.

Additionally, if `s'il` should not be matched because it only has a length of maximum 2, then `(?=[a-zA-Z'-]{3,}['-])([a-zA-Z'-]+)` may be good. For more explanations: [this answer is good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31911114/16521194).

EDIT: Added hyphen to regex.
Pay attention to the fact that the only thing missing was the hyphen that needed to be added to the regex. `-` and `–` are different characters!

Comment: Thanks, I saw my mistake about step 3. But how can I do the same with a hyphen? With the words "Allez-y! Regarde–le!" unfortunately not working. Output is 'allez', 'regarde'